# Is there a glitch with AMP by Example's Geolocation-based Consent Flow?

Tags: geolocation, amp-html

Hi Stack Overflow Community,

I am working with the Geolocation-based Consent Flow found here: https://ampbyexample.com/user_consent/geolocation-based_consent_flow

The issue is that the geolocation-based consent message is displaying on both US & EU browsers rather than only EU.

When I append the custom country codes to the example,

EU: https://ampbyexample.com/user_consent/geolocation-based_consent_flow/#amp-geo=de

non-EU: https://ampbyexample.com/user_consent/geolocation-based_consent_flow/#amp-geo=us

I'm still seeing the consent message on both examples. However, the documentation says:

> In this sample we'll build a consent dialog that will **only show for users from the EU.**

Similarly, when I added a Geolocation-based Consent Flow to my own website, I have the same issue:

EU: https://marcelluslong.com/amp/#amp-geo=de

non-EU: https://marcelluslong.com/amp/#amp-geo=us

Here is the AMP HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum- 
scale=1,initial-scale=1">
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<title>My Consent Form</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/items/55555" />
<script async custom-element="amp-consent" 
src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-consent-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-geo" 
src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-geo-0.1.js"></script> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One" rel="stylesheet">
<style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
<style amp-custom>
.ampstart-btn,.ampstart-btn:visited{color:#DFE4E4}.ampstart-btn{font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;font-weight:500;font-size:1rem;line-height:1.4;padding:.7em .8em;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;vertical-align:middle;cursor:pointer;background-color:#7e50bb;border:1px solid #8c62c2}.ampstart-btn:active .ampstart-btn:focus{opacity:.8}.ampstart-btn[disabled],.ampstart-btn[disabled]:active,.ampstart-btn[disabled]:focus,.ampstart-btn[disabled]:hover{opacity:.5;outline:0;cursor:default}.ampstart-btn-reject{background-color:#bb5058;color:#fff;border:1px solid #bb5058}.ampstart-btn-reject:visited{color:#fff}.ampstart-btn-accept{background-color:#8dbb50;color:#fff;border:1px solid #8dbb50}.ampstart-btn-accept:visited{color:#fff}.m1{margin:1rem}.consent-msg {font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;font-weight:400;}.consent-headline {font-family: 'Patua One', cursive; font-size:36px;}.consentPopup{padding:20px;margin:0 auto;background:#F8F7D3;border-radius:5px;position:relative;max-width:700px;width:95%} .popupOverlay{height:100vh;width:100vw;background:F8F7D3;padding:5% 0}.dismiss-button{position:absolute;right:24px;top:16px;cursor:pointer} .amp-caps {text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: 0}.popupOverlay p{ color: #333333; padding:15px; }.mx1 {margin-left: 0rem}.mx1{margin-right: 0rem}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<amp-geo layout="nodisplay">
<script type="application/json">
{
"ISOCountryGroups": {
"eu": ["al", "ad", "am", "at", "by", "be", "ba", "bg", "ch", 
"cy", "cz", "de", "dk", "ee", "es", "fo", "fi", "fr", "gb", 
"ge", "gi", "gr", "hu", "hr", "ie", "is", "it", "lt", "lu", 
"lv", "mc", "mk", "mt", "no", "nl", "po", "pt", "ro", "ru", 
"se", "si", "sk", "sm", "tr", "ua", "uk", "va"]
}
}
</script>
</amp-geo>

<amp-consent id="myUserConsent"
layout="nodisplay">
<script type="application/json">
{
"consents": {
"eu": {
"promptIfUnknownForGeoGroup": "eu",
"promptUI": "myConsentFlow"
}
},
"postPromptUI": "post-consent-ui"
}
</script>
<div id="myConsentFlow"
class="popupOverlay">
<div class="consentPopup">
<div class="dismiss-button"
role="button"
tabindex="0"
on="tap:myUserConsent.dismiss">X</div>

<div class="h3 option-font m1 consent-headline">Please choose an option.</div>
<p class="m1 consent-msg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <a href="https://example.com/privacy-policy-amp.pdf">Learn more</a>. 
</p>
<button on="tap:myUserConsent.accept"
class="ampstart-btn ampstart-btn-accept amp-caps mx1">I accept 
cookies</button>
<button on="tap:myUserConsent.reject"
class="ampstart-btn ampstart-btn-reject amp-caps">I refuse 
cookies
</button>
</div>
</div>

<div id="post-consent-ui">
<button on="tap:myUserConsent.prompt()"
class="ampstart-btn amp-caps m1">Manage my cookie settings</button>
</div>
</amp-consent>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/cixoruliko/edit?html,output

**AMP version: 1528841168349**

Am I experiencing a glitch with AMP by Example's Geolocation-based Consent Flow or is it something else? Any constructive input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the test parameters to work, you need to enable the AMP Dev Channel via: https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html (first checkbox).

Comment: Hello, thank you for the information. I did enable the AMP Dev Channel & I'm experiencing the same thing. However, I was under the impression that amp-geo & amp-consent are not experimental features. Is that correct? I am also testing the the pages without the parameters.

Comment: They're out of experiment, this is just to ensure that test links only work in development mode. I just verified it and it works as intended. If that's not the case for you, please file a bug report with a your detailed setup here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new.